# KnockOut.js to call function AFTER all values have been assigned to dropdown?

Tags: knockout.js

I am writing a knockout script and have a function that is called whenever a value of an observable changes.  One of the elements that calls this function is a dropdown list.  The function that is called sends the entire viewmodel to the server for storage.

What happens is that the function is called when the dropdown is being initialized, and calls to the server twice.  I am wondering if there is a way to not act on the value change until **after** all of the fields have been initialized?

Comment: Please include the relevant code; even if it does not work correctly, it will show us what you have tried..  You ill get a faster and better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information or example code, my best guess is you're not initializing the observable when binding it to a list. Or that you set it to a value that does not exist in the list.

A dropdown always selects the first item in the list after it's bound. Knockout will select the item in a list if it matches the value of the observable.

See this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/xxz32L1q/

```
// uninitialized item
self.Item1 = ko.observable();

// pre-initialized item
self.Item2 = ko.observable("c");
```

Item1 isn't initialised - so when the list binds, the first item is selected and the Item1 value is the assigned that value. Hence you see Item1 changed in the log.

Item2 is initialised to 'c' - when that list binds, no event is fired because Item2 does not get changed.

A common pattern used is to have a special or blank value in the list, e.g.

```
<select>
  <option value=''>[please select an option]</option>
```

Setting the observable to a blank string would match the first entry and not cause the event to fire.

Comment: Hi Quango, thank you so much for your very thoughtful and precise answer!  It has helped me tremendously and I appreciate you sharing your knowledge with me and us.  Wishing you all the best!